# How to run your own python code on amazon sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I have a python code which uses keras and tensorflow backend. My system doesn't support training this model due to low memory space. I want to take use of Amazon sagemaker.

However all the tutorials I find are about deploying your model in docker containers. My model isn't trained and I want to train it on Amazon Sagemaker.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT :** Also can I make a script of my python code and run on it on AWS sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker provides the capability for users to bring in their custom training scripts and train their algorithms using the script it on SageMaker using one of the pre-built containers for frameworks like TensorFlow, MXNet, PyTorch.

Please take a look at https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/frameworks/tensorflow/get_started_mnist_train.ipynb

It walks through how you can bring in your training script using TensorFlow and train it using SageMaker.

There are several other examples in the repository which will help you answer other questions you might have as you progress on with your SageMaker journey.